# Why is SignalR starting up to 8 servers per Blazor Server app start?

Tags: c#, blazor, asp.net-core-signalr, azure-signalr

When I start my Blazor Server app, I can see in the SignalR service that 8 servers are connected. I don't understand why.
My goal is that MyRazorPage is able to send and receive (from itself or some Azure Function) SignalR messages without creating so much (unnecessary?!) servers.

Here is my code and below are the DI service registrations I'm using:

***Code***

**MyRazorPage.razor**

```cs
@inject IHubConnectionFactory HubConnectionFactory // see HubConnectionFactory.cs below
```

**MyRazorPage.razor.cs**

```cs
public sealed partial class MyRazorPage
{
    private HubConnection _hubConnection;
    
    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        if (_hubConnection is not null)
        {
            _hubConnection.Remove("MyMethodName");
            await _hubConnection.DisposeAsync();
        }
    }
    
    private async Task HandleHubMessageReceived(ResultDto result)
    {
        // handle received result
    }
    
    private Task SendMessage()
    {
        // ... 
        await _hubConnection.SendAsync("MethodName", new ResultDto(Guid.Parse(CustomerId), ResultEnum.Success));        
    }
    
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {  
        _hubConnection = HubConnectionFactory.CreateHubConnection();
        await _hubConnection.StartAsync(CancellationToken);
        _hubConnection.On<ResultDto>("MyMethodName", HandleHubMessageReceived);
    }   
}
```

***Setup, service registrations, SignalR middleware***

**Package references**

```html
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.SignalR" Version="1.24.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client" Version="8.0.1" />
```

**appsettings.json**

```json
"Azure": {
   "SignalR": {
     "Enabled": "true",
     "ConnectionString": "Endpoint=URL;AccessKey=KEY;Version=1.0;"
   },
 "SIGNALR_REFRESH_BILLING_PAGE_URI": "https://localhost:44362/MyHub",
```

**Startup.cs**

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSignalR();
    services.AddSignalRHubConnection(config =>{
               config.ConnectionString = Configuration["SIGNALR_REFRESH_BILLING_PAGE_URI"] ?? 
               string.Empty;
               });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseRequestLocalization(app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>().Value);

    if (!env.IsProduction())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                     {
                         endpoints.MapControllers();
                         endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                         endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                         endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
                         endpoints.MapHub<MyHub>($"/{MyHub.HubName}");
                     });
}
```

**HubConnectionFactory.cs**

```cs
public class HubConnectionFactory : IHubConnectionFactory
{
    private readonly SignalREndpointConfiguration _configuration;
    
    public HubConnectionFactory(IOptions<SignalREndpointConfiguration> configuration) => _configuration = configuration.Value;
    
    public HubConnection CreateHubConnection()
    {
        return new HubConnectionBuilder()
               .WithUrl(_configuration.ConnectionString)
               .Build();
    }  
}
```

**MyHub.cs**

```cs
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public const string HubName = "MyHub";

    public async Task SendMessage(ResultDto dto)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("MyMethodName", dto);
    }
}
```

I also tried the following things, but without any success:

| Approach | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Removed "Azure setting" from appsettings.json | HandleHubMessageReceived is not invoked anymore. |
| Added services.AddCors() to ConfigureServices in Startup.cs and app.UseCors(policy => policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyOrigin() to Startup.Configure() | No difference |

Comment: What's HubConnectionFacotry?

Comment: It's just the class that uses the HubConnectionBuilder to create a new HubConnection whenever needed. The HubConnectionFactory constructor parameter SignalREndpointConfiguration stores the endpoint URL for the HubConnectionBuilder.WithUrl().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can see in the SignalR service that 8 servers are connected. I don't understand why.

[image]

**That's what you're talking about, right?**

#### It's server connections, not servers.

Here is the official document about [How connections are counted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-concept-messages-and-connections#how-connections-are-counted).

And **server_connections_count** = **1** instance * **2** hubs * **5** (default value).
                                                       = **10**

Tips: Default value is 5 --> [InitialHubServerConnectionCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-use#initialhubserverconnectioncount)

If you want to reduce the connection count, you can refer to the official documentation.

[Configure options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-signalr/signalr-howto-use#configure-options)

***Why 8 server connections in your azure portal metrics?***

There should be a delay, in the charts in Azure Portal, the statistics may be related to the time span, so the data you see may have slight deviations, you can check it by looking at more detailed statistics.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Correct, your screenshot shows what I'm talking about. You answered my question! 
But I have one follow-up question: Is there a way my app is using the Blazor SignalR for "componenthub" instead of the Azure SignalR service or is it by design? Since I added the Azure SignalR service, every SignalR message is sent to it. This results in having thousands of messages by just opening some razor pages.

Comment: Hi @lizard. I remember Blazor was using asp.net core signalr, which I think is design-related, you can raise a new github issue in  ask asp.net core if there are any plans to implement your requirements.

Comment: Hey @Jason Pan, thank you again and you are completely right. Unfortunately, this is by design as stated here: [Stop Blazor SignalR from sending requests to Azure SignalR](https://github.com/Azure/azure-signalr/issues/1738). So I'll have to be patient on this issue. Thanks once again for your help and pointing me into the right direction!